# jquery guillotine plugin with ajax image update

Tags: jquery, image-processing

I am using jquery guillotine plugin for zoom and resize and i am updating image src through ajax call but on change i am not getting cordinate basicaly guillotine('getData') returning nothing,below is my my code which i am using.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       picture = jQuery('#sample_picture');
       picture.guillotine('fit');
       picture.on('load', function(){
        picture.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});
        var img = jQuery(this);
        img.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});
       // Remove any existing instance
       if (img.guillotine('instance')) img.guillotine('remove');
               img = jQuery('#sample_picture');
               img.guillotine({width: 387, height:594});
               img.guillotine('fit');
       if (! img.data('bindedBtns')) {
               img.data('bindedBtns', true)
               jQuery('#fit').click(function(){ img.guillotine('fit'); });
               jQuery('#zoom_in').click(function( { img.guillotine('zoomIn'); });
               jQuery('#zoom_out').click(function(){ img.guillotine('zoomOut'); });
       }
       var data = img.guillotine('getData');
        if(data){
               for(var key in data) {alert(data['key']); jQuery('#'+key).html(data[key]); }
        }
        // Bind button actions
        jQuery('#rotate_left').click(function(){ img.guillotine('rotateLeft'); });
        jQuery('#rotate_right').click(function(){ img.guillotine('rotateRight'); });
        jQuery('#fit').click(function(){ img.guillotine('fit'); });
        jQuery('#zoom_in').click(function(){ img.guillotine('zoomIn'); });
        jQuery('#zoom_out').click(function(){ img.guillotine('zoomOut'); });
           // Update data on change
           img.on('guillotinechange', function(ev, data, action) {
          data.scale = parseFloat(data.scale.toFixed(4));
          for(var k in data) { jQuery('#'+k).html(data[k]); }
        });
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380545/jquery-guillotine-swap-image#27408843) but it seems like you've just pasted conflicting code from different sources.

On the third line you atempt to fit the image even before having an instance of the plugin and later you instantiate it three times on the same image:

- `picture.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'})`
- `img.guillotine({eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'})`
- `img.guillotine({width: 387, height:594})`

You also bind buttons to actions (rotate, zoom, etc.) and parse data twice.

I would sujest to start with something simpler like Guillotine's own [example](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine/blob/master/demo/index.html#L49) and only when you get that working move on to something more complex like loading images over AJAX and swaping the `src` attribute.