# Reinstatiating javascript for image crop

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, image, crop

I'm trying to cobble together a function for a user to select an image for their avatar, preview it on the page using javascript, select the crop using the jquery guillotine, then upload it to the server w/ the coordinates where it can be processed.

So far I can select an image to upload and it will appear in the preview, but guillotine needs the image to be already loaded when it is invoked. Is there a way that I can force guillotine to re-load when I select an image?

This is my code:

```
<head>
<script src="{% static "assets/js/user_profile.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("id_avatar").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("avatar_preview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };
    };  
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='file' id='id_avatar' name='avatar' onchange="PreviewImage();" /><br />
        <div id="parent" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img id="avatar_preview" src="#" alt="your image" style="width:400px;" />
</div>
</body>
```

And this is what's in my user_profile.js, which is what I'd like to reinstantiate when I change the avatar input:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var picture = $('#avatar_preview')

  var camelize = function() {
    var regex = /[\W_]+(.)/g
    var replacer = function (match, submatch) { return submatch.toUpperCase() }
    return function (str) { return str.replace(regex, replacer) }
  }()

  var showData = function (data) {
    data.scale = parseFloat(data.scale.toFixed(4))
    for(var k in data) { $('#'+k).html(data[k]) }
  }

  picture.on('load', function() {
    picture.guillotine({ eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange' })
    picture.guillotine('fit')
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) { picture.guillotine('zoomIn') }

    // Show controls and data
    $('.loading').remove()
    $('.notice, #controls, #data').removeClass('hidden')
    showData( picture.guillotine('getData') )

    // Bind actions
    $('#controls a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      action = camelize(this.id)
      picture.guillotine(action)
    })

    // Update data on change
    picture.on('guillotinechange', function(e, data, action) { showData(data) })
  })

  // Display random picture
  picture.attr('src', 'img/unsplash.com_' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25) + '.jpg')
})
```

Is there a way to wrap that into something that can be reloaded without reloading the page and losing the preview?

Comment: Jason, I'm not familiar with Guillotone so please forgive me for being naïve, but could you clarify *"it will appear in the preview, but guillotine needs the image to be already loaded when it is invoked"* please. In that context, what does "loaded" mean? From the browser perspective, surely the image is loaded if it's in preview, so is it an issue of responding to an `img.onload` event?

Comment: Hi, I meant when the page is first loaded, the <img> tag is empty, since it's a preview of what's in the <input id="id_avatar" />. Guillotine requires the <img> already contain the actual image when it's loaded (when the page is loaded), so it won't restart. Is it possible to tie Guillotine to an img.onload event?

Comment: The code is taken from the Guillotine demo and appears to be largely correct for your app. You might try calling `picture.guillotine('remove');` before `picture.guillotine('fit')` in case the `picture.onload` event fires a second time. If your preview code is working, then you shouldn't need `picture.attr('src', 'img/unsplash.com_' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25) + '.jpg')`, which was necessary in the Demo.

Comment: Is it possible to enclose the entire guillotine call in a function that would get called when the input is chosen?

Comment: For sure, you *could*, but I think that event would be too early for the preview image to be loaded. By all means try it but I think that what you already have is more likely to work.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give me some clarification? Right now it doesn't work because it expects the image to be in there when the page loads. I don't understand where to change it so that it only instantiates after the user has selected an image.

Comment: No, it doesn't expect the image to be there on page load. If that was the case, then the demo on the Guillotine site wouldn't work. The `picture.on('load', function() {...}` wrapper ensures that guillotine is instantiated only after the image has loaded. Try getting a copy of the demo working, then see if you can modify it to work with your preview image.

Answer (score 0):

With a few modifications you can achieve what you want. First off, Guillotine's [code demo](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine/blob/master/demo/index.html#L49) is much easier to follow than the code from the [display demo](http://guillotine.js.org).

Whenever you set a preview (change the `src` attribute) the image will be loaded and an `onload` event will be triggered (eventually). You only care about when new previews finish loading, you don't need to worry about changes on the file input.

So, focus on **reloading** the plugin each time the image finishes loading, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380545/jquery-guillotine-swap-image#27408843). Basically it boils down to:

```
picture.on('load', function() {
  // Reload the plugin (remove existing instance if any and create a new one)
  if (picture.guillotine('instance')) picture.guillotine('remove')
  picture.guillotine({ eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange' })

  // Bind buttons, only once! (to avoid overlaps)
  if (! picture.data('bindedBtns')) {
    picture.data('bindedBtns', true)
    $('#rotate_left').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateLeft') })
    $('#rotate_right').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateRight') })
    // ...
  }
}
```

You might also find [Presto](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/presto) quite useful. It's sole purpose is to **display image previews from file inputs**. It gracefully falls back looking for the best available way to display the previews.

If you also pair it up with [Bifrost](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/bifrost) the last attempt will be to upload the image asynchronously and get the preview from the server (no need for HTML5, XMLHttpRequest or Flash) so you can be sure you'll get a preview on any browser.

Unfortunately I haven't had the time to complete Presto's readme but the [source](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/presto/blob/master/src/jquery.presto.coffee#L29) is very clean and at the top you'll find documentation for it's API and features.

Hope it helps.