# JQuery Guillotine: Multiple Change Events Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody please give me some guidance with a problem I am having with the JQuery Guillotine?  I have spent hours working on this and cannot identify the correct solution.  The issue I am having is eventOnChange fires multiple times after I have changed the image.  Each event is fired +1 for each successive image swap.

I have studied this link and am still unable to find a working solution:  [jQuery Guillotine - Swap Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380545/jquery-guillotine-swap-image)

I've worked around this by killing the event and just capturing the relevant information I need when the form is posted, but it's really bothering me that I cannot find a solution that will allow me to take advantage of the event.

Here is a brief summary of what is going on:

1. page loads with default user avatar
2. user is able to manipulate avatar inside guillotine and one onchange event fires per manipulation (zoom in, zoom out, rotate, fit, etc.)
3. user opens file reader to select new avatar
4. new avatar is successfully loaded (correct scaling and dimensions)
5. user manipulates image but each manipulation event fires multiple times.  For example, rotate right will rotate the image twice (180 degrees) after the user has selected a new avatar.
6. If the user opens the file reader again, the image will fire three times. And so one.  1 + x times the user selects a new avatar...

I have tried unbinding the event before reloading the image and initialing the plugin, but it has not solved the problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Relevant code is below.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
function showData (data) {
  data.scale = parseFloat(data.scale.toFixed(4))
  for(var k in data) { $('#'+k).html(data[k]) }
}

function loadInterface(picture) {
  showData(picture.guillotine('getData'))

  // Bind button actions
  if(!picture.data('isBound')){
    picture.data('isBound', true)
    $('#rotate_left').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateLeft') })
    $('#rotate_right').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('rotateRight') })
    $('#fit').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('fit') })
    $('#zoom_in').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomIn') });
    $('#zoom_out').click(function(){ picture.guillotine('zoomOut') })
  }

  // Update data on change
  picture.on('guillotinechange', function(e, data, action) { 
    console.log('guillotine onchange event called!')
    showData(data);
    console.log(action); 
  })
}

function loadGuillotine (picture, data) {
  if(picture.guillotine('instance')){ picture.guillotine('remove') }

  // Load plugin
  picture.guillotine({
    width:  data['w'],
    height: data['h'],
    init:   data,
    eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var picture = $('#useravatar')
  var data    = { w: 250, h: 250, angle: 0, scale: 1 }

  picture.on('load', function() {

    // Load guillotine and controls
    picture.guillotine('remove')
    loadGuillotine(picture, data)
    loadInterface(picture)

    // Transform picture to fit, center
    picture.guillotine('fit').guillotine('center')
  })
})

function ReloadImage(){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("avatar_input").files[0]);
  reader.onload = function (oFREvent){
    document.getElementById("useravatar").src = oFREvent.target.result;
  }  
}
</script>
```

And inside Ruby Page:

```
<div id='content'>
  <h1>Select Avatar</h1>

  <%= form_for(@avatar, url: save_avatar_path, method: :patch) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @avatar %>

    <div class='frame'>
      <%= image_tag 'default-user-avatar.jpg', :id => :useravatar %>
    </div>

    <div id='controls'>
      <button id='rotate_left'  type='button' title='Rotate left'> &lt; </button>
      <button id='zoom_out'     type='button' title='Zoom out'> - </button>
      <button id='fit'          type='button' title='Fit image'> [ ]  </button>
      <button id='zoom_in'      type='button' title='Zoom in'> + </button>
      <button id='rotate_right' type='button' title='Rotate right'> &gt; </button>
    </div>

    <div id='controls'>
      <%= f.hidden_field :image, value: @avatar.cached_image_data %>
      <%= f.file_field :image, :class => :form_field, :id => :avatar_input, :onChange => "ReloadImage()" %>
    </div>

    <ul id='data'>
      <div class='column'>
        <li>x: <span id='x'></span></li>
        <li>y: <span id='y'></span></li>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <li>width:  <span id='w'></span></li>
        <li>height: <span id='h'></span></li>
      </div>
      <div class='column'>
        <li>scale: <span id='scale'></span></li>
        <li>angle: <span id='angle'></span></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested your code but *believe/guess* you have fallen into a trap that I once found myself in.

.click() applies your function event with every iteration of the loop hence why you get multiple change events fireing (thus if the loop calls three times then the event is added sequentially three times).

Try using .[one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of .click()

Another potential solution is to use .off().click() but it creates overhead.

Comment: I don't think it's the click function.  While the event fires multiple times on click, the event also fires multiple times when the image is loaded when this line is executed:  // Transform picture to fit, center
    picture.guillotine('fit').guillotine('center')  I believe multiple listeners are attached after each successive image change.